# Почему не срабатывает ввод имени второго кота?

Tags: java, обработка-ошибок

```
package fightClub;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите имя первого кота: ");
        String nameFirstCat = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите вес первого кота: ");
        int weigthFirstCat = scanner.nextInt();

        Cat firstCat = new Cat();
        firstCat.setName(nameFirstCat);
        firstCat.setWeigth(weigthFirstCat);

        System.out.print("Введите имя второго кота: ");
        String nameSecondCat = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Введите вес второго кота: ");
        int weigthSecondCat = scanner.nextInt();

        Cat secondCat = new Cat();
        secondCat.setName(nameSecondCat);
        secondCat.setWeigth(weigthSecondCat);

        System.out.println(firstCat.getName() + " " + 
firstCat.getWeigth());
        System.out.println(secondCat.getName() + " " + 
secondCat.getWeigth());


}
```

}

Консоль:
Введите имя первого кота: Lory
Введите вес первого кота: 5
Введите имя второго кота: Введите вес второго кота: 6
Lory 5
6

Comment: Всякое может быть, но лучше уточнить язык и показать код

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: scanner.nextInt() - нет перехода на новую строку. сделайте так: Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После считывания веса первого кота int weigthFirstCat = scanner.nextInt(); необходимо считать пустую строку, т.е. добавить scanner.nextLine(); тогда все заработает.
Можно представить, что после считывания числа сканнером за числом остается невидимый пустой символ, на этой же строчке

P.S. в слове "weigth" опечатка, вес будет "weight"